# Block https facebook via file hosts

Tags: blocking, facebook

I need to block access to Facebook in my office on certain PCs that are connected to a LAN. I tried using the hosts file, it works for www.facebook.com but not for https://it-it.facebook.com/, how can i block that ? Maybe block all Facebook IPs ? I have a firewall but my PCs doesn't have static IPs so i can't block only the PCs i want to.

Comment: You could try blocking all of Facebook's IP addresses. The following IP address ranges belong to Facebook: 66.220.144.0 - 66.220.159.255 and 69.63.176.0 - 69.63.191.255 and 204.15.20.0 - 204.15.23.255

Comment: That's the Italian FB login, are you going to block every language? What about proxies? I'd recommend addressing the problem rather than the symptoms.

Comment: This is a field many network admins face and, without a proxy server and/or firewall that can be configured to reject requests to an entire domain using web filters etc, you'll find it very difficult to achieve with the resources and configuration you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately - and sorry to be the bearer of bad news - the windows hosts file does not support wildcards or similar.  It would be brilliant if *.facebook.com could be put into HOSTS, but it wouldn't work.

This leaves you with the following choices:

- Company proxy to filter web traffic by groups
- lots of lines in your hosts files (it-it.facebook.com, facebook.com, static.fbcdn.com etc)
- some sort of dns blocking program... have a quick google around and see what you can find, there are a few good free ones out there
- Block facebooks IP range on your router.  [this link](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-control/content-filtering/how-to-block-facebook-789.html) lists all of their IP ranges.

Comment: My problem is the fact that my PCs doesn't use static IPs, so i have to work on the single machine i need to block. I tried to block it-it.facebook.com but it doesn't work, that would be enough for me.